# Using Share Dialog of Facebook on Fragments and Viewpager

Tags: android, facebook, android-fragments, share

I have implemented a tab layout using fragments and viewpager. However, on my fifth tab, I want to share where the user is on the google maps, which is on the third tab. This is my code for my "Share on Facebook" tab.

**TabFour.java**

```
public class TabFour extends Fragment {
private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_tab_four, container, false);

    return rootView;
}

public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(this, callback);
        uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data, new FacebookDialog.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookDialog.PendingCall pendingCall, Exception error, Bundle data) {
            Log.e("Activity", String.format("Error: %s", error.toString()));
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete(FacebookDialog.PendingCall pendingCall, Bundle data) {
            Log.i("Activity", "Success!");
        }
    });
}



@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    uiHelper.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    uiHelper.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    uiHelper.onDestroy();
}
private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {


    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
            Exception exception) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
};

}
```

However, there is an error on this line:

```
 uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(this, callback);
```

and the error says:

```
 The constructor UiLifecycleHelper(TabFour, Session.StatusCallback) is undefined
```

What could be the possible problem? There is no other methods for the UiLifecycleHelper on Facebook Developers. Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Document say :

```
public UiLifecycleHelper(Activity activity, Session.StatusCallback callback)
```

Creates a new UiLifecycleHelper.
Parameters

> activity: the Activity associated with the helper. If calling from a Fragment, use Fragment.getActivity()
>   callback: the callback for Session status changes, can be null

For more information you can check this link:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/UiLifecycleHelper

Answer (score 0):

That's because the `this` you're using refers to the Fragment, not an Activity, which is what the constructor requires. Try replacing `this` with `getActivity` (or if you're using ABS, `getSherlockActivity`)

Answer (score 0):

I know I am replying late, but I hope this will help all others..
In your fragment class call this..

```
FragmentActivity activity=getActivity();
```

Now in UiLifeCycleHelper constructor, pass activity instead of "this"

```
uiHelper=new UiLifeCycleHelper(activity, CallBack);
```

Answer (score 0):

On Facebook SDK 4.x UiLifecycleHelper is replaced with CallbackManager. To implement Facebook Share Dialog in a fragment now is easier:

1) OnCreateView in your fragment class:

```
 CallbackManager mCallbackManagerFacebook;

// Facebook Share
mCallbackManagerFacebook = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
```

2) In your app class:

```
// Facebook
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
```

3) Override onActivityResult in your fragment class with:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            mCallbackManagerFacebook.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
 }
```

4) For example, you have a button that OnClickListener the user can share a photo:

```
ImageButton fbBtn = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.facebookHomeDetailButton);
        fbBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                mProgressBar.setSpinSpeed(10);
                mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mProgressBar.spin();

                if (ShareDialog.canShow(ShareLinkContent.class)) {

                    ParseFile fileObject = (ParseFile)mParseObjectsList.get(mPosition).get("thumbnail");

                    fileObject.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
                        public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {
                            if (e == null) {
                                Log.d("test", "We've got data in data.");

                                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
                                SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder()
                                        .setBitmap(bitmap)
                                        .build();

                                SharePhotoContent content = new SharePhotoContent.Builder()
                                        .addPhoto(photo)
                                        .build();

                                mShareDialogFacebook.show(getActivity(), content);

                                mProgressBar.stopSpinning();
                                mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


                            } else {

                                Log.d("test", "There was a problem downloading the data.");

                            }

                        }

                    });


                } else {

                    showDialogWithOk("¡Ooops!\nParece que no tienes Facebook instalado en tu dispositivo. Para compartir tendrías que instalar esta aplicación en tu dispositivo.\n¡Gracias!");

                }






            }
        });
```

5) That´s all. I hope that this code can help.

Comment: This is perfect, except you omit where the shreDialog is actually initialised. Do you do it in the Fragment?  I receive an error unless the Share Dialog is in the Activity.